# Form View how to check the mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, formview

Hi I'm using a asp:FormView and I need to set some inner control accessibility based on whether it's in Insert or Update mode.

Can anyone tell me how you find the mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually just found the answer CurrentMode property